# jQuery push giving a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am pushing objects using `push` in js.

I am appending this object into html:

```
var top = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {                                                   
    var file= something[i];
    top.push(file);     
};

jQuery('.place').append(top);
```

I am noticing that there is a comma in between the `file` variable:

```
<div class="place"> 
   <div class="name">something</div>
   ,
   <div class="name">else</div> 
</div>
```

I am guessing this comma is there as the result of `push` event.

How do I get rid of it?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Has nothing to do with push. `var x = [1,2]; console.log(x.toString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an `array` of strings to jQuery's `append` method. Simply join it first:

```
jQuery('.place').append(top.join(''));
```

When you call `toString()` on an array (which is what jQuery is doing here when you try to `append` an array of strings) it casts each array element to a string and puts a comma between them:

```
[1,2,3].toString(); //"1,2,3"
[{a:"b"},2,3].toString(); //"[object Object],2,3"
```

Comment: I thought about that too, but you can append an array: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @Gavriel - the OP is not passing an array of nodes (which jQuery accepts), it's an array of strings, which is why the comma is there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it looks there's a problem using `top` as variable name, so I changed it to top1.

THEORY:
According to http://api.jquery.com/append/ you can pass an array of DOM elements, or String(s) (or other things, but they're not related to the question). You seem to pass an array of strings, that is not an array of DOM elements, so it's being stringified, and the stringification of an array has commas between the elements. I'm pretty sure you also have a "[" before them and a "]" after them.

PRACTICE: Well, I don't seem to reproduce your problem (at least in Chrome, FF, Safari):

```js
var top1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {                                                   
    var file = "<div>something[i]</div>";
    top1.push(file);     
}

$('#place').append(top1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="place"> 
</div>
```